# Div Alignment CSS Issue

Tags: html, css

I am new to css. I am having an alignment issue in one of my html pages. I have created an invoice page, which can be viewed at: https://www.w3schools.com/code/tryit.asp?filename=G6HQYBZLNH3Y .
When you will open this page you will notice that one of DIVs is slightly more to the right and one of its edge is pointing out. i have tried multiple things but i am unable to set its alignment. I will be really thankful if anyone can solve this issue.

Comment: Why margin left and right to -15px ? remove it and see

Comment: Add your code to your question. Also which `div` are you talking about?

Comment: The div with the  Shipping Total text.

Answer (score 0):

The Bootstrap .row class adds negative margin to the left and right, and the .col classes add padding to the left and right. You have tried to counteract this padding by adding columns to the container to wrap your rows which in turn wrap additional columns.

Try removing those wrapper columns. This will allow the previous rows with black backgrounds to extend further, the text will line up better, and then the div in question won't extend further than the previous rows.

https://www.w3schools.com/code/tryit.asp?filename=G6HS3SOMWWM8\

[image]